# Image with max-width, and set height

Tags: html, css

I have a lightbox of photos and each photo is assigned a height of 85% of the viewport. When the window width is too small, the image is cut off, so they have a max-width of 100%;

```
.modal-image {
    height: 85vh;
    max-width: 90%;
}
```

However, when the max-width kicks in, the image is distorted because the height remains 85vh while the width changes with the screen width.

How could I keep the images at height 85vh except for when the max-width kicks in, at which point the height should be dynamic.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You might have a chance using a container for your image, so you could set the `max-width` in the container and the `height` on the image like so:

```css
div {
  max-width: 90%;
}

img {
  height: 85vh;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div> <img src="https://pixar-community-production.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/News/Effects_MTL_2018/rfm_rewrite.jpg" /> </div>
```

Using a container with a `max-width` allow us to have the right width, then using `height`on the image allow the image to dynamically calculate its width without loosing its ratio.

Comment: It works as long as I add in object-fit: contain; or else the image's width is not dynamic. With object-fit, it's solved!

Comment: Just updated the answer, you should accept it if it’s ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Update: found an alternative solution

simply gave the image a container of width 85vh and height 85vh, and used object-fit: fill; so that the images scale properly.

```
<div class="container">
        <img src="https://www.aussiespecialist.com/content/asp/en/sales-resources/image-and-video-galleries/jcr:content/mainParsys/hero/image.adapt.1663.medium.jpg" class="modal-image">
     </div>

     <style>

         .container {
             width: 100%;
             height: 100vh;
             padding: 100px;
             object-fit: contain;
         }

         .modal-image {
             width: 100%;
             height: 100%;
         }

     </style>
```

Comment: use `object-fit:cover`

Comment: If you were to type this up as a complete / legit solution, with code and a runnable snippet, I'd upvote it.  As-is, while technically correct, it's not as useful as it could be.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look in which screen resolution, the window "becomes" too small and create a css rule specific for every case. For example:

```
<style>
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .modal-image {
          height: 85vh;
          max-width: 90%;
      }
    }
    @media (max-width: 1200px) {
      .modal-image {
          height: 85vh;
          max-width: 90%;
      }
    }
</style>
```

Greetings!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I do have quite a few images with varying widths, and it would be quite tedious to make a media query for every image width.

Comment: Looking for something that works for all image widths, but if not I may have to stick it out and use media queries. Thanks again